# How to prove the binomial theorem with real exponent without using Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, binomial-theorem

**Question.** Prove $(1+x)^r=1+rx+\frac{r(r-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$, where $r$ is a real number, **without** using Taylor (including Maclaurin) series.

---

**Origin.** In a class, the teacher was proving the derivative of $x^n$ where $n$ is a real number by the definition of differentiation $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{f}(x+h)-\operatorname{f}(x)}{h}$
. During the process, the binomial theorem with real exponent was used. However, when I looked up the proof for the binomial theorem, every single one used the Taylor series which assumed the polynomial differentiability which was to be proven! By the way, anyone knows the technical term for such a situation, i.e. it is like using a corollary to prove the theorem from which the corollary is derived?

---

**Attempt.** About seven months ago one of my teachers presented a proof but I forgot how it went exactly. I only remember that it started with $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$, and somehow he derived the series expansion of $\ln(x)$ from that, and then I think that he expressed $(1+x)^r$ as $e^{r\ln(1+x)}$. So the problem boils down to how to derive the series expansion of $\ln(x)$ from the series expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: I have described such a proof in my blog post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html?m=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The r.h.s can be written

$$I_r(x) = \sum_{k =0}^\infty A_{k,r} \frac{x^k}{k !},$$
where $A_{0, r} = 1, \,\, A_{k,r} := r (r-1)\cdots(r-k+1), k\geq 1.$

Working on the sum itself, we get
$$I'_r(x) = \sum_{k =1}^\infty A_{k,r} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1) !}.$$
Multiplying with $(1+x),$ we get
$$(1+x) I'_r(x) =\sum_{k =1}^\infty  A_{k,r} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1) !} + \sum_{k =1}^\infty  A_{k,r} \frac{x^k}{(k-1) !}.$$
Now, we change the index inside each sum,
$$(1+x) I'_r(x) =\sum_{k =0}^\infty  A_{k+1,r} \frac{x^k}{k !} + \sum_{k =0}^\infty  k A_{k,r} \frac{x^k}{k !}.$$

The last step is to prove that $$A_{k+1, r} + k A_{k, r} = r A_{k , r}.$$
Finally, we get
$$(1+ x) I'_r(x) = rI_r(x)$$ which is a first order DE that you can solve easily.

Comment: Hi, $\pi$. No offense. But I am not sure if you got my question. I do not assume the validity of the binomial theorem; I want to prove the binomial theorem with real exponent without using Taylor series which uses the fact $\frac{d}{dx}(x^r)=rx^{r-1}$ which needs proof. @A. PI

Comment: I didn't assume that you have to use Taylor series. You just to need to work on the sum.

Comment: Sorry, bro. What is your logic here? I did expand as you suggested and I got $I'_r(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}$ which is true. @A. PI

Comment: Please have  a loot at my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, bro. I still do not get your framework of proof here. So you assumed the validity of the RHS and tried to both-way derive something which is true? @A. PI

Comment: Just forget the LHS and start with the RHS. Call it $I_r$ and differentiate it with respect to $x.$  Multiply it with $(1+x).$ Do some operations on the resulting sums. Finally, you get the differential equation $(1+x)I' = r I$ whose solution is the LHS of the problem.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot for your patience. This method is great! @A. PI

Comment: You are welcome. :)